# Prime that divides $a^2-1$ but not $a-1$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, prime-numbers, divisibility, integers

I saw in our book that for any integer bigger than $1$, say integer $a$ there is a prime $p$, such that $p$ divides $a^2-1$ but not $a-1$ or otherwise $a$ is one smaller than power of two.

Why is that true?

Comment: Hint: how can you simplify $(a^2 - 1)/(a-1)$?

Comment: This is true when $a+1$ and $a-1$ are twin primes. if $p=a+1$ then p does not divide $p-1$.

Comment: Can you give more hits please?i still don’t understand why it’s true

Comment: $a^2-1$/$a-1$ is $a+1$

Comment: Any prime other than $2$ that divides $a+1$ does not divide $a-1$.

Comment: For example 3 and 5 are twin primes; $3=4-1$ and $5=4+1$, now if p=5 that is $p|4+1$ then 5 does not divide $3=4-1$.

Comment: If it’s not hard can someone please give some kind of prove? Or just explain why it that true?

Answer (score 3):

Since $a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)$, we know that any prime $p$ that divides $a^2-1$ divides either $a-1$ or $a+1$ or both. So we are interested in primes $p$ that divide $a+1$ but do *not* divide $a-1$.

For any positive integers $m$ and $n$ with $m>n$ we know that any common factor of $m$ and $n$ is also a factor of $m-n$. But if $m=a+1$ and $n=a-1$ then $m-n=2$, so either $\gcd(a+1,a-1)=1$ i.e. $a+1$ and $a-1$ are coprime *or* $\gcd(a+1,a-1)=2$.

Now consider these two case separately:

- If $a+1$ and $a-1$ are coprime then ...
- If $\gcd(a+1, a-1) = 2$ then
  ...